# Calling a method with a return type of void that only prints

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public static void boardSelection(String selectionBoard) //Setting up the board
{ 
    if(selectionBoard.contains("1")){ //3x3
        char[][] board= new char[3][3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int o=0;o<3;o++){
                board[i][o]='X';
            }
        }


        System.out.println(" ___________________");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|  "+board[0][0]+"  |  "+board[0][1]+"   |  "+board[0][2]+"   |  ");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|-------------------|");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|  "+board[1][0]+"  |  "+board[1][1]+"   |  "+board[1][2]+"   |  ");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|-------------------|");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|  "+board[2][0]+"  |  "+board[2][1]+"   |  "+board[2][2]+"   |  ");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println(" -------------------");     
    }
}
```

How do I call it at the main method if I need it to print? I tried syso and I tried some other stuff, but couldn't find any other answer.

Comment: If it's in the same class, it would just be `boardSelection(myStringVar);` somewhere in your `main` method.

Comment: I'd suggest reading/watching some tutorials before asking questions as these. This is programming 101. You're literally calling methods in your code, what would make your method different?
As long as you're in the same (static) class, just call the method of the name and give it its parameter, if it's in a different (static) class, call it with ClassName.Method(<params>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it with ClassName.staticMethodName(String parameter)

```
 public class SelectionBoardCls{
        public static void boardSelection(String selectionBoard) //Setting up the board
{ 
    if(selectionBoard.contains("1")){ //3x3
        char[][] board= new char[3][3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int o=0;o<3;o++){
                board[i][o]='X';
            }
        }


        System.out.println(" ___________________");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|  "+board[0][0]+"  |  "+board[0][1]+"   |  "+board[0][2]+"   |  ");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|-------------------|");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|  "+board[1][0]+"  |  "+board[1][1]+"   |  "+board[1][2]+"   |  ");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|-------------------|");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println("|  "+board[2][0]+"  |  "+board[2][1]+"   |  "+board[2][2]+"   |  ");
        System.out.println("|     |      |      |");
        System.out.println(" -------------------");     
}
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String selectionBoard = "some1111";
            SelectionBoardCls.boardSelection(selectionBoard);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call it in the main() using the Function_Name:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
String selectionBoard=<>;
boardSelection(selectionBoard);
}
```

Comment: You should only pass it selectBoard and not String selectionBoard.

Comment: yes you are right, I overlooked it. It was a mistake, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it's name and pass it a string:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    boardSelection(selectionBoard);
}
```